# issue opening ifstream with string (c++)

Tags: c++, ifstream, stringstream

I am having a strange issue while opening an ifstream in c++. 
Inside a function I am reading a file which contains a label (this is working fine), and with this label I build a stringstream that will contain the complete filename.

```
ifstream infile1;
infile1.open("label.txt");
int a;
infile1 >> a;
stringstream stream1;
stream1 << "./Path1/filename_" << a << ".txt" ;
string pathfile(stream1.str());
```

After that I need to pass the contents of the stream to a function as a reference to string in order to open an ifstream object. The first lines of this function look like this:

```
void Function(string &pathfile, ..., ...){
    ifstream inFile2;
    inFile2.open(pathfile.c_str());
    if(inFile2.fail()) cerr << " Error opening file " << endl;

    ...
}
```

This procedure doesn't work, I keep getting "Error opening file" message. I tried to print out the contents of the stringstream and of the string in both functions and they both correspond to the filename looked for.
Strangely the procedure works fine in the case I am not passing through the `stringstream`, that means when I am manually writing to a `string` the exact file path and passing the string to `function1`.

```
string filepath2 = "./Path1/filename_1.txt";
function1(filepath2,...,...);
```

I can't figure out what sort of issue the stream is giving.

Comment: Is the file in the current working directory of the program? If, for example, you are running from an [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) the working directory of the program is most likely not the same directory as where the executable program file is.

Comment: Hm. Relative path, eh? I bet you're misunderstanding how that resolves when you run your program.

Comment: What happens if `a` is changed to an "exact" type like an `int`, insead of a `double`?

Comment: @Alberto: Sorry, it is actually an int, I edited. 
The executable is in the current working directory, and the directory Path1 is placed inside it as the relative path shows. Passing to `function1` a string manually written inside the function, and holding the exact same contents as the stringstream (I check printing on screen), works fine.

Comment: Ok, but printing on screen might hide some detail. Try comparing the string coming out of the stringstream with the manually typed string by using the `==` operator, or comparing them byte by byte. Maybe some detail went wrong, or there is some issue with the `\0` terminator.

Comment: Comparison with `==` fails, but I think we could already tell by the fact that the result they give is different. What do you mean by comparing them byte by byte?

Comment: Something like `for (char c : str1) cout << +c << " ";` and the same for the manually typed string. In this way you can immediately find at which character does the differences begin, and detect possible hidden special characters than won't show up just by printing the string.